# Best way to factorize controller code using $scope

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, refactoring

My AngularJS 1 (+Ionic) application is handling various types of data (Employee, Company, ...), and there is one controller for each type and view.

Currently there is a lot of code identical between controllers, for instance the piece below used to delete an entity with a modal dialog box for confirmation.

I would like to factor this into one function or service or whatever, that I would call from each controller, but don't know what to do as this code is using $scope, $ionicModal and $ionicHistory.

Could you please tell me how to proceed? Many thanks!

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl("templates/delete-modal.html", {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
    $scope.text = "Delete entity?";
});

$scope.delete = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
}
$scope.doDelete = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
    databaseService.remove($scope.entity);
    $ionicHistory.goBack(-2);
}
$scope.doCancel = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're permitted to pass in `$scope` to the service methods. `$ionicModal` and `$ionicHistory` should be injected.

So create a service that injects `$ionicModal` and `$ionicHistory`. Defined your methods on the service, taking in `$scope` as an argument.

In each controller, pass in the `$scope` to the respective function of the service method.